# Clicking on CI Pagination links produces wrong queries

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I'm currently having problem when clicking on they pagination link of my site using CodeIgniter. The search function works fine, however, when I click on any of the pagination links, it seems like it does the filter again and again.

For example:

I choose "Rent" as my choice to search for:

[image]

Then click search I get 27 results. After that I click on the "2" pagination button at the bottom:

[image]

I get another 73 results and so on and so forth.

[image]

My Controller:

```
$this->load->library('pagination');
$search['base_url'] = base_url() . 'page_search/';
$search['per_page'] = 5;
$search['num_links'] = 5;
$search['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$search['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$search['first_link'] = 'First';
$search['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="first">';
$search['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$search['last_tag_open'] = '<li class="last">';
$search['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$search['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$search['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$search['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$search['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$search['last_link'] = 'Last';
$search['next_link'] = '&raquo;';
$search['prev_link'] = '&laquo;';
$search['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination pagination-centered"><ul>';
$search['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></div>';
$search['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
$search['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
$search['total_rows'] = $this->db->get_where( 'listing', $where )->num_rows();
$search['uri_segment'] = 2;
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;

$this->pagination->initialize( $search );
$this->db->order_by("id", "desc");
$this->db->where( $where );
$data['results'] = $this->db->get( 'listing', $search['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(2);
$data['rows'] = $this->db->get_where( 'listing', $where )->num_rows();

$data['content'] = 'website/page-search';
$this->load->view('template/website/theme', $data);
```

Which $where is the query which I am sure it works fine.

**UPDATE:**

Also I have this in my route:

```
$route['page_search/(:num)'] = "page_search/index/$1";
```

Here's the link to the live site http://angkor21.com/

Answer (score 1):

You are posting your search form and making your `$where` statement, thats cool, but in page 2, is your `$where` statement working correctly? I think this is where you need to watch out for. Print your generated query in the second page like this:

```
$this->db->last_query();
```

You need to somehow pass on these `search parameter(s)` to the next page to correctly generate the `$where` condition. For example:

```
if( $this->input->post(null) ){     #if the form is submitted
    $saleType   = $this->input->post('sale_type');
    $propType   = $this->input->post('prop_type');
    $city       = $this->input->post('city');
    $district   = $this->input->post('district');
    $commune    = $this->input->post('commune');    
}else{
    $saleType   = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $propType   = $this->uri->segment(5);
    $city       = $this->uri->segment(7);
    $district   = $this->uri->segment(9);
    $commune    = $this->uri->segment(11);
}


$search['base_url']     = base_url() . 'page_search/sale_type/'.$saleType.'/prop_type/'.$propType.'/city/'.$city.'/district/'.$district.'/commune/'.$commune.'/page/';
$search['uri_segment']  = 13;
```

Comment: Ah, I see. I have printed the last query result in view. It shows that when clicking on the pagination button, the query re-runs.

Comment: I still have a problem when users do not select some of the options. Is there anyway which u think would be more flexible than this?

Comment: use a default value for each of the search fields, like all types, all communes and so on..